# How to fix "Type Error : Invalid Dimensions for image data" error when I view an image using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to convert an image to grayscale and show it using pyplot. The steps I am taking are:

Step 1: Reading an image as input using Pillow in python

Step 2: Converting it into grayscale image using `.convert('LA')`

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = Image.open('28.jpg').convert('LA')
img.save('greyscale.png')

img=np.array(img)
print (img.shape)
plt.imshow(img)
```

Which outputs this as the shape of the `np.array`:

```
(360, 480, 2)
```

The problem is when I try to view the output of this grayscale image using matplotlib.pyplot it throws the following error error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-f6fac0acd82f> in <module>
      1 img = np.array(img)
      2 print (img.shape)
----> 3 plt.imshow(img)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in imshow(X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, data, **kwargs)
   2697         filternorm=filternorm, filterrad=filterrad, imlim=imlim,
   2698         resample=resample, url=url, **({"data": data} if data is not
-> 2699         None else {}), **kwargs)
   2700     sci(__ret)
   2701     return __ret

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1808                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1809                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1810             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1811 
   1812         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in imshow(self, X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, **kwargs)
   5492                               resample=resample, **kwargs)
   5493 
-> 5494         im.set_data(X)
   5495         im.set_alpha(alpha)
   5496         if im.get_clip_path() is None:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in set_data(self, A)
    636         if not (self._A.ndim == 2
    637                 or self._A.ndim == 3 and self._A.shape[-1] in [3, 4]):
--> 638             raise TypeError("Invalid dimensions for image data")
    639 
    640         if self._A.ndim == 3:

TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

*This is the image I am trying to read and convert it into grayscale*
[28.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZLML.jpg)

Comment: Use `.convert('L')` as shown in the duplicate. (Because jpg images don't have an alpha channel anyways)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to save the image as an `np.array`, just give the converted image to `plt.imshow()` directly. Like this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = Image.open('28.jpg').convert('LA')
img.save('greyscale.png')

plt.imshow(img)
```

You can still store the image as an `np.array` is you want to, just make sure to give it a different name.

Also, if you want to show the image, don't forget to put `plt.show()` at the end.

Comment: I am still getting the same error message

Comment: @SanjayMoharana Try it in fresh, it works.

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou   Its not working.Its still throwing same error message.

Comment: @SanjayMoharana Can you post the full error traceback in your question?

Comment: @SanjayMoharana Looking at the error traceback, you did not try my answer because you're still storing the image as an `np.array`.

Comment: @funie200 The error still persists even after not storing the image as numpy array and adding plt.show() at the end.I just executed your solution including plt.show() at end in a fresh ipython notebook but still i am getting this error.

Comment: @SanjayMoharana Are you even listening my friend, what funie200 said? You are not trying the answer. Do not convert to Numpy array please.

Comment: @SanjayMoharana Works fine for me, what is the image that you are trying to show?

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou    You are not getting me...I have exactly tried his solution **without converting the image into numpy array** and just simply tried to output the grayscale image. I am still getting the same error even after executing the same code

Comment: @funie200 I am trying to show the grayscale image

Comment: @SanjayMoharana Yes I know, but can you upload the image to SO, so I can test it with the exact image you are using. The `28.jpg` image.

Comment: @SanjayMoharana Tell us something about the image you have.

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou  The image link is given above. And what I am trying is to convert 28.jpg into grayscale image and save it in the respective directory.Meanwhile the  grayscale image is getting saved but when I am trying to visualise this image as output then I am seeing this error.